# Conversion of string to date type while passing from vb.net to sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net-2010

I had the same issue while passing date variable from vb.net to SQL Server. I tried with Parameters as suggested above. Still I am facing the same issue. Pl guide.

```
Dim today As String
today = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
Dim todate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(today, "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
SQLCom.CommandType = CommandType.Text
SQLCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TODAY", CType(todate, Date))
SQLCom.CommandText = "SELECT DATEDIFF(MM,FORMAT(UPD_DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy'),FORMAT(@TODAY,'dd-MM-yyyy')) AS DATE_DIFF FROM tblEMP WHERE EMPID = '" & ID & "';"
Try
        Dim daEmpExp As New SqlDataAdapter
        daEmpExp.SelectCommand = SQLCom
        SQLConn.Open()
        daEmpExp.Fill(dsEmpExp)
        SQLConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Sorry!!! " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        If SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQLConn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End If
Return dsEmpExp
```

Still it catches error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: You should edit your question. It is not properly formatted.

Comment: I think your problem relates from switching from MM-dd to dd-MM

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to convert date to string back and forth? Try to simply pass `DateTime.Now` as sql command parameter :

```
SQLCom.CommandType = CommandType.Text
SQLCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TODAY", System.DateTime.Now)
SQLCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
SQLCom.CommandText = "SELECT DATEDIFF(MM,FORMAT(UPD_DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy'),FORMAT(@TODAY,'dd-MM-yyyy')) AS DATE_DIFF FROM tblEMP WHERE EMPID = @ID;"
Try
    ......
End Try
```